# ビルトインライブラリのソースコードを見るには

Tags: python, python3, qt

PySideでWordライクなエディタを作っています。
常に、PySide Documentationなどのリファレンスを
見て、それを組み合わせて使っているのですが、
関数は、全てブラックボックスのため、中でどのような
処理が行われているのか、外からは全く見る事ができません。
こうした基本的なコードが、どのように成り立っているのか
は、見る事ができるのでしょうか？
　継承関係や、メソッドならリファレンスに書いてあります。
Summerfield氏の本にも、`QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`や
`QTextLayout`については、全く書かれていません。
しかし、その中身のコードが、どういう仕組みになっているの
かを知りたいのですが、どなたかご存知ありませんか？
　目的は先日から質問をしている`QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`
の、メソッドの中身を見て、それを基本的なものとして、改良を
加えたいと思いました。ご存知の方はどうか教えてください。
　リファレンスは各所にありますが、役所のたらいまわしのようです。
役所の受付の内側や、考えの仕組みを知りたいのです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qtのラッパーですから、結局のところC++で書かれたQtのソースを見ることになると思います。
QAbstractTextDocumentLayoutなら以下のところでしょうか。

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/text/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.cpp

Comment: 非常に私にとって有益な情報なのですが、一つ確認させていただきたい事があります。PyQtもPySideも元々C++　Qtが前身だという事はわかるのですが、①C++ Qt →②Pythonコード化(PyQt/PySide化)→③ユーザーの利用という事だと思ったのです。つまり、Python化されたソースがあるのではないか、という期待感をまだ持っています。それとも、①をコンパイルとかしたら、③の状態になるということでしょうか？`QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`は上記の①をコンパイル等して、PySider達が使えるようになっているという事で、間違いないでしょうか？最も求めているものは、PyQt/PySideリファレンスのメソッドのブラックボックスの中身を知ることができるものです。

Comment: たとえば、 http://docs.python.jp/3.6/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils などは、**C++の側に**Pythonから呼び出されるためのコードを追加し共有ライブラリ（soファイル）とそれを呼び出すPyhtonコードを生成します。PySideはShibokenという独自のライブラリを作ったみたいで詳細が不明ですが、普通ならPythonコード側には「C++のこの関数を呼び出す」程度の記述しかないはずです。

Comment: なるほど、つまり机の向こうはC++人しかいなかったということですね。呼び出す私はPySideメソッドの机を看つつ、いつのまにかC++サイドを呼び出して今までプログラムを組んでいたということですか。わかりました。C++の勉強もしながら、長いスパンでこの問題をクリアしていけるようにします。ありがとうございました。